# Export CEWP as .webpart file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, content-editor

I'm trying to export my Content Editor webpart from SP2013 environment, and I expect output file in .webpart format. Currently I'm getting output file in .dwp format.

Any idea how to get Content Editor webpart in .webpart format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you getting the *.dwp file which basically a XML. Content editor is not behaves like *.webpart. What you can be done is export the file as its and import in the visual studio in a empty module. Deploy it..it will be visible in the web parts section. I hope after then you know what to do.

Following post would be useful: [How to add content editor web part to webpart gallery| Export content editor web part (OOTB in SharePoint)](https://kushanlahiru.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/how-to-add-content-editor-web-part-to-webpart-gallery-export-content-editor-web-part-ootb-in-sharepoint/)

Reference: [Export CEWP as .webpart file - Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181412/export-cewp-as-webpart-file)

Answer (score 0):

The briefly answer is just replace the extension .dwp with .webpart, it will work because its just an XML file.

From what I know dwp is the old extension used by SharePoint to export webparts, I'm not sure what situation triggered that change in your environment due to you are using SP 2013, however from my perspective its not that critical because you can use both extensions to upload the webpart to a different location, also you can still see the same XML code if you open the file with a text editor.

You may have other reasons to consider it an imporant issue however you haven't provided too much details about your scenario, I'm just assuming you just want to export and import the CEWP to other page, if this is not the case please provide more details and I will update my answer according to your situation (if possible).